# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a HEIC image into WebP format using Pillow and [pillow-heif](https://github.com/bigcat88/pillow_heif) library (Pillow does not support HEIC natively). I ran into a weird issue where if I try to convert it into any other formats, it would work just fine, but for WebP, it threw `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'` rather than with an output of a `.webp` image.

Minimal reproducible code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pillow_heif import register_heif_opener

register_heif_opener()
image = Image.open("test.HEIC")
image.save("test2.webp", format="webp", lossless=True, exif=None)
```

Full stack trace for the above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\image-uploader\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    image.save("test2.webp", format="webp", lossless=True, exif=None)
  File "C:\Users\Mint\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\image-uploader-Qxb7pR67-py3.10\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2300, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Mint\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\image-uploader-Qxb7pR67-py3.10\lib\site-packages\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py", line 329, in _save
    data = _webp.WebPEncode(
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'
```

Edit: I tested it the other way by opening a sample `.webp` file and saved it as `.heic` and that worked fine, just not the other way around.

Comment: The `exif=None` in your function call looks suspicious.

Comment: @MarkRansom The kwarg is documented here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp and it does work too. I thought of it but removing it still got me the same problem with the NoneType thing. Pillow actually tries to ignore kwargs if the parameter is non applicable for a format as well afaik so I think it's pretty safe.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `format`, `lossless`, and `exif` options? If that works try adding each of them back one by one to find which one causes the issue.

Comment: @EricJin Turns out @MarkRansom was right about the `exif=None` being suspicious, apparently it only works if `[...] the system WebP library was built with webpmux support.` and I was under the assumption it comes natively with the library since the parameter worked for all other file formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `exif=None` caused the problem because it is "only supported if the system WebP library was built with webpmux support" (I'm on Windows) as stated in [Pillow's docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp) and I was under the assumption that it is supported natively since it worked for other formats. I wrote a method as an alternative to remove the exif before saving it:

```
def strip_exif(image: Image) -> Image:
    data = list(image.getdata())
    image_without_exif = Image.new(mode=image.mode, size=image.size)
    image_without_exif.putdata(data)
    return image_without_exif
```